# Photoshop CS tool display problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm using Photoshop CS and can't seem to display the top-upper-left tool highlighted in red in the image below:

[image: photshop snip]

Can anyone explain how I can display this tool?

Comment: You mean access it or make use of it in the image?

Answer (score 1):

Select the Gradient tool (press G). It may be 'behind' the Paintbucket tool, in which case, left click and hold on the Paintbucket tool until you get a drop down menu.